# Apache Webdav, unable to create "test" folder when file test.txt exists

Tags: apache, webdav

I'm having a unusual problem with Ubuntu Server, Apache, Webdav and haven't been able to find an answer.

If I create a folder/file called "test.txt" then create a folder/file "test", it says the file already exists. If I delete "test.txt", then I can create a folder/file "test" it works. I can also create both from the command line on the server. Can be names other then text, e.g. jquery.ui.zip and ./jquery.ui/

I've tested is on a public server and I can create both, so I assume it's not a webdav limitation, but perhaps my configuration or apache2 webdav module causing the problem.

Perms seem ok, as I can create/copy/delete folders/files. Just a problem with naming collisions. Due to the large amount of files involved, it's simply not practical to rename them all.

Any help welcome, a nudge in the right direction would be good,

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName [removed]
    ServerAlias [removed]

    ServerAdmin [removed]
    DocumentRoot /home/projects/

    ErrorLog /home/projects/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    #Options Indexes None

    #   SSL Engine Switch:
    #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
    SSLEngine on

    #   A self-signed (snakeoil) certificate can be created by installing
    #   the ssl-cert package. See
    #   /usr/share/doc/apache2.2-common/README.Debian.gz for more info.
    #   If both key and certificate are stored in the same file, only the
    #   SSLCertificateFile directive is needed.
    SSLCertificateFile    [removed]
    SSLCertificateKeyFile    [removed]

    Alias /projects /home/projects/

    <Directory /home/projects/>
        Options Indexes MultiViews

        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars

        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Location /projects>
        DAV On
        AuthType Digest
        AuthName "webdav1digest"
        AuthUserFile [removed]
        Require valid-user

        ForceType text/plain

        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars

        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 192.168.1.0/24
    </Location>

    # fixes a problem with several clients - redirects for folders with DAV methods.
    BrowserMatch "Microsoft Data Access Internet Publishing Provider" redirect-careful
    BrowserMatch "MS FrontPage" redirect-carefully
    BrowserMatch "^WebDrive" redirect-carefully
    BrowserMatch "^WebDAVFS/1.[0123]" redirect-carefully
    BrowserMatch "^gnome-vfs/1.0" redirect-carefully
    BrowserMatch "^gvfs/*" redirect-carefully
    BrowserMatch "^XML Spy" redirect-carefully
    BrowserMatch "^Dreamweaver-WebDAV-SCM1" redirect-carefully
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I'm going to rebuild with debian 7.3

Comment: Same problem. Can create test folder, then test.txt file. But not other way around, e.g. test.txt then test folder ... file exists.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `AllowOverride None` and `Options None` seemed to fix the problem.

```
<Location /projects>
    DAV On

    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    ForceType text/plain

    AuthType Digest
    AuthName "webdav1digest"
    AuthUserFile [removed]
    Require valid-user

    #SSLOptions +StdEnvVars

    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 192.168.1.0/24
</Location>
```