# A requested privilege is not held by client (Apache2 + WebDAV)

Tags: php, windows, apache, webdav

This is driving me crazy. I have a Apache2 server with WebDAV enabled on my Debian Wheezy server. I can access it and read from it and it appears to be running correctly.

From my Windows 7 laptop I am running a software called NetDrive2 that mounts a network drive to my WebDAV folder so that I can access it with a drive letter.

Whenever I try to copy files from the Windows 7 laptop to my WebDAV drive, I sometimes get the error message:

Error 0x80070522: A required privilege is not held by the client."

The WebDAV folder has Basic AuthType and I have ofc provided correct user/pass. It is not SSL.

I have done some debugging myself and I am not sure, but it appears that I cannot create a folder that has the same name as a file in the same directory:

Folder:
 - file.php
 - file/ (cannot create this dir because file.php exists).

Anyone have any ideas? I am stuck!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apache Webdav, unable to create "test" folder when file test.txt exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20695683/apache-webdav-unable-to-create-test-folder-when-file-test-txt-exists)

Answer (score 0):

OK so Googling further I finally found what was causing the problem. I cannot believe this is not mentioned in any tutorials out there.

This guy gave me the answer:
[Apache Webdav, unable to create "test" folder when file test.txt exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20695683/apache-webdav-unable-to-create-test-folder-when-file-test-txt-exists)

Basically, you have to add `AllowOverride none`, and `Options None` to your webdav directory.

This is my final configuration for my webdav host in Apache2:

```
Alias /devshed /home/www/sites/dev
Alias /devsheddav /home/www/sites/dev

<Directory /home/www/sites/dev/>
        AllowOverride none
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Options +Indexes +MultiViews
        IndexOptions FancyIndexing
</Directory>


<Location /devshed>
        DAV Off
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AuthName "Pennybridge Devshed Web"
        AuthType Basic
        AuthUserFile /home/www/htaccess/sites/dev/dev.htpasswd
        Require valid-user
</Location>

<Location /devsheddav>
        DAV On
        Options None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AuthName "Pennybridge Devshed WebDAV"
        AuthType Basic
        AuthUserFile /home/www/htaccess/sites/dev/dev.htpasswd
        Require valid-user
        php_flag engine off
        BrowserMatch "Microsoft Data Access Internet Publishing Provider" redirect-carefully
        DirectoryIndex disabled
</Location>
```